# My image is overlapping my text in mobile res even though its on flex col and justify between

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

[image]

```
function Project({ title, image }) {
  return (
    <div className="bg-[#ffffff] py-5 rounded-lg my-10 shadow-2xl relative py-10">
      <h2 className="text-2xl px-5 font-semibold">{title}</h2>
    <div className="flex justify-between md:flex-row flex-col">
        <div>
          <img src={image} alt="" className="lg:w-1/2 p-5 drop-shadow-lg z-10"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul className="py-10 ab px-5 z-50">
            <li> asdasd</li>
            <li> asdasd</li>
            <li> asdassssssssssssssssssssssd</li>
            <li> asdasd</li>
            <li> asdasd</li>
            <li> asdasd</li>
            <li> asdasd</li>
            <li> asdasd</li>
            <li> asdasd</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  )}

export default Project;
```

I tried everything still its not working

Comment: your code just works fine, you have to check this part of code in another page to detect if the problem comes from the parent components, because this part works fine as well

Comment: Have you tried checking in the dev tools?

Comment: Thank you guys i fixed it , It was due to the auto absolute nature of the image i made it relative now its fixed Thank youuu